# How to add gridview.xml to main.xml?

Tags: android, xml, gridview

It was working fine before i moved my gridview code to grid_view.xml because i wanna reuse the grid_view.xml. Before i move my gridview, I just replace the ViewFlipper now to my whole gridview code. I thought it's fine because in my onCreate it can detect the id even if i put in another folder. The error is at the line

```
gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Anyone can help? :<

In my onCreate :

```
gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
adapter = new MyGridViewAdapter(this, arrImages);
gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

In main.xml :

```
<ViewFlipper xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/vf"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <include android:id="@+id/gridViewLayout" layout="@layout/grid_view" />

</ViewFlipper>
```

In my grid_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="1dp"
    android:numColumns="3"
    android:gravity="center"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

</GridView>
```

Comment: what does the error say in the logcat? cant find the layout?? try taking out the (android:id="@+id/gridViewLayout") or have look here http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html --- maybe merge might help

Comment: @Tasos omigosh the id why :O i removed and it kinda worked :O thanks and the link thankss

Comment: Just use the ID of GridView itself, no need to give an ID again while including.

Comment: thankss hehe @dgngulcan :>